# Search database with special character

Tags: php, mysql, get

How to search the database with special character?

I use this code to as a button

```
<a href="search.php?search=A & W Restaurants&submit=submit">A & W Restaurants</a>
```

After that, I use this to search database

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1st_column LIKE '%{$query}%'
```

But the search result show me is empty.

I think is "&" to stop my database query.

any idea on this?

Thanks for advance

Comment: TRy replacing `&` with `&amp;` in your a href ...

Comment: Please, oh ***please*** use a prepared statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think this url "search.php?search=A & W Restaurants" is vaild

please url encode it - A & W Restaurants

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1st_column='$query'
```

I don't know about how your setting the search but to get a value colume='to_value' sould work better then like if like is even a select comanned

Comment: Please don't ever actually try this in code that is exposed to the Internet. It's a textbook SQL-injection vulnerability.